# Determining element with nonexisting following element in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the below XML:

```
<li>angels</li>
<dt>Famous or respected graffiti artists who have died.</dt>

<li>PP</li>
<dt>Point to Point</dt>

<li>goodbye</li>

<li>Hello</li>
<dt>Alloo, say to people</dt>
```

I want to find each word with its definition (if existing)?

`output:`

> [
>   ('angels', 'Famous or respected graffiti artists who have died.'),
>   ('PP', 'Point to Point'),
>   ('goodbye', null),
>   ('Hello', 'Alloo, say to people')
>   ]

or

> [
>   ('angels', 'Famous or respected graffiti artists who have died.'),
>   ('PP', 'Point to Point'),
>   ('Hello', 'Alloo, say to people')
>   ]

But the problem is sometimes the definition does not exist, I want to identify those cases

How can I do it with XPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check to see if the first following-sibling was not `dt`...

```
//li[following-sibling::*[1][not(self::dt)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0,

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="li">
  ...
</xsl:for-each-group>
```